# How to get records from 3 diff tables via ASP.NET Core Web API request

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API application to access a SQL database.

I then used scaffold to generate the models for the 3 tables (TB1, TB2, TB3) and the DbContext.

`TB1` model includes all its properties but also includes a `LIST<>` for `TB2` class as follows:

```
public virtual ICollection<TB2> TB2s { get; set; } = new List<TB2>();
```

`TB2` model includes all its properties but also includes a `LIST<>` for `TB3` class as follows:

```
public virtual ICollection<TB3> TB3s { get; set; } = new List <TB3>();
```

In the controller, I included the TB2s

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> Get() => await _context.TB1s.Include(c => c.TB2s).ToListAsync();
```

THIS WORKS!!

But the model still returns empty `TB3s : [ ]`

So I added the following code to TB1 class

```
public virtual ICollection<TB3> TB3s { get; set; } = new List<TB3>();
```

Now I can try to include it the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> Get() => await _context.TB1s.Include(c => c.TB2s).Include(p => p.TB3s).ToListAsync();
```

but it still does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a multi-level model, you should use the **ThenInclude** method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Patient>> Get() => await _context.TB1s.
Include(c => c.TB2s).ThenInclude(p => p.TB3s).ToListAsync();
```

Read [Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) for more information

Comment: Many thanks Vahid, that worked great!
The link is very informative as well